# How to change a character in a list of strings to lowercase if it matches a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings in capital letters, and I want to change some of the characters to lower case since they are measure units or abbreviations.

I am new to regular expressions, but I managed to get two regex that fit what I need: one for the 'X' placed within numbers, another for the rest of the cases needed.

The problem is that it changes the whole pattern (as you can see "--") and what I want is that the letters in regex rules become lowercase.

```
t1 = 'EXTRUDED PROFILE 50 X 50 MM'
t2 = 'MATERIAL TYPE 3XP WITH A DENSITY OF D= 50KG/M3 AND THICKNESS OF E=8MM'
t3 = 'STEEL TUBE 50X50X3 MM'
list_Txt = [t1, t2, t3]

pattern_X = r'(\d\s?X\s?\d)'
pattern_M = r'(E=|D=)?\s?\d+\s?(X|MM|KG/M)|d+\.(MM)'

new_Txt= [re.sub(pattern_X,'--', item) for item in list_Txt]
```

Returns:

`'EXTRUDED PROFILE 5--0 MM', 'MATERIAL TYPE 3XP WITH A DENSITY OF D= 50KG/M3 AND THICKNESS OF E=8MM', 'STEEL TUBE 5---- MM'`

I want:

`'EXTRUDED PROFILE 50 x 50 mm', 'MATERIAL TYPE 3XP WITH A DENSITY OF d= 50kg/m3 AND THICKNESS OF e=8mm', 'STEEL TUBE 50x50x3 mm'`

Answer (score 3):

You may use this python solution with a lambda to lowercase matched text:

```bash
import re

t1 = 'EXTRUDED PROFILE 50 X 50 MM'
t2 = 'MATERIAL TYPE 3XP WITH A DENSITY OF D= 50KG/M3 AND THICKNESS OF E=8MM'
t3 = 'STEEL TUBE 50X50X3 MM'
list_Txt = [t1, t2, t3]

pat = re.compile(r'(?:[ED]=\s*)?(?:\d+\s*X\s*)*\d+\s*(?:M[MG]|KG/M)')

new_Txt= [pat.sub(lambda m: m.group().lower(), item) for item in list_Txt]

print (new_Txt)
```

**Output:**

> `['EXTRUDED PROFILE 50 x 50 mm', 'MATERIAL TYPE 3XP WITH A DENSITY OF d= 50kg/m3 AND THICKNESS OF e=8mm', 'STEEL TUBE 50x50x3 mm']`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGuW8r/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:[ED]=\s*)?`: Optionally match `E=` or `D=` followed by 0 or more whitespaces
- `(?:\d+\s*X\s*)*`: Match 1+ digits followed by 0+ spaces followed by `X`. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(?:M[MG]|KG/M)`: Match `MM` or `MG` or `KG/M`

Comment: Thank you @anubhava this is exactly what I need, I have been trying for many days :)